# Two questions about tensor products

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I didn't take a linear algebra class in undergrad, but have picked up a fair bit by osmosis when learning QM. I'm hoping someone can help me to understand a particular topic -- namely tensor products.

Imagine I have two entangled particles denoted particle 1 and particle 2, with respective 2D Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ spanned by the basis vectors $|\alpha\rangle$ and $|\beta\rangle$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ spanned by the basis vectors $|\gamma\rangle$ and $|\delta\rangle$, and I entangle them and express the entangled state as an arbitrary superposition that lives in $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$: $$|\psi\rangle=A|{\alpha},{\gamma}\rangle + B|{\alpha},{\delta}\rangle + C|{\beta},{\gamma}\rangle + D|{\beta},{\delta}\rangle\tag{1}$$ Now imagine I make a projective measurement and post-select for cases where I measure particle 2 in the state $|\gamma\rangle$. This is equivalent to acting on my state in (1) with the projection operator $|\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma|$, so I can express my new state as: $$|\psi'\rangle=|\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma|\psi\rangle=A|{\alpha},{\gamma}\rangle+0+C|\beta,\gamma\rangle+0\tag{2}$$ Where I've used $|\gamma\rangle\langle\gamma|(|i\rangle\otimes|j\rangle)=\delta_{\gamma,j}|i\rangle\otimes|\gamma\rangle$

And $|\psi'\rangle$ can be factored to become: $$|\psi'\rangle=|\gamma\rangle\otimes(A|\alpha\rangle+C|\beta\rangle)\tag{3}$$

My first question pertains to the fact that I've read in multiple places that in (3), we've effectively eliminated all entanglement. *Physically* this makes perfect sense. If we've projected the state (1) onto a state where only the states where particle 2 is in state $|\gamma\rangle$ survive, we've eliminated any information about particle 1 which can be obtained from particle 2. Measuring particle 2 and finding it in $|\gamma\rangle$ tells us nothing about the state of particle 1. I'd like to understand this better on a formal level, however. In (3), can we simply get rid of the tensor product altogether, since it is effectively a formality? If so, where do the dimensions of our Hilbert space which we are losing "go"?

Then my second question is this: from what I understand of the operation of the "partial trace", which I've only just started learning about, it seems like that's all that I've done between (1) and (3). Is this the case? If so, can someone explain the exact formal relationship between the partial trace and the projective measurement + post-selection scheme I've worked with here?

Comment: By projecting for states where particle 2 is exactly in $|\gamma\rangle$, you are formally looking at a subspace of your total Hilbert space dimension. So your original Hilbert space is of dimension $4\times 4$, but the projector takes only into account basis states for which particle 2 is in $|\gamma\rangle$. So dimensions don't go anywhere, you are just restricting the study to a subspace region of the full Hilbert space (in this particular example, the subspace is of dimension $2\times 2$) . In the partial trace you are tracing out the states for which particle 2 is in $|\delta\rangle$.